# Firefox strange connection established, what is this?

Tags: connection, tcpip, malware, firefox

I have accidentally found inside Firefox process properties (using Process Explorer) a weird connection in tcp/ip tab:

**bandicam.com**:*some_ports*

it points at localhost **127.0.0.1**:*some_ports*

bandicam is desktop recording software that I had installed year ago.

I can't find in web any information of that connection, and I have feeling that it is not native for Mozilla

I had also disabled all addons, the problem didn't go away.

Do you have any clue?

[image]

Comment: Guess that bandicam software installed some extension in the firefox browser. You can run firefox in safe mode and see if it is still there. Check firefox help and bandicam site for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is DX 10/11 hooking for recording Firefox, also available for Internet Explorer.

To disable this, go into Advanced options in Bandicam and the tab Hooking.

Visit this link and scroll down to [Advanced] - Hooking:
http://www.bandicam.com/support/settings/general/